# Styling Custom UITableViewCell Using UIAppearance

Tags: ios

I have a custom UITableViewCell and I want to style that using the UIAppearance protocol.

```
@interface MyCell : UITableViewCell<UIAppearance>
{

}

@property (nonatomic,weak) UIView *backgroundCellView UI_APPEARANCE_SELECTOR;



 MyCell.m: 

  -(void) setBackgroundCellView:(UIView *)backgroundView
{
    NSLog(@"setBackgroundCellView");

    [super setBackgroundView:backgroundView];
}
```

In the app delegate I am doing the following:

```
  [[MyCell appearance] setBackgroundCellView:[UIImageView .... with an image]];
```

It assign the background to few cells but not all the cells. Usually the assigned ones are in the middle.

Comment: [check this out working code with video](http://46media.net/xcode-turorials/customize-the-appearance-of-uitableview-and-uitableviewcell-in-xcode-4/)

Comment: The code in the video does not use the UIAppearance protocol. What happens when I want to customize 10 UITableViews.

Comment: well it serves the purpose for changing the background of the uitableview, you can make a customcell for that purpose i suppose

Answer (score 0):

One cannot assigning the same UIImageView to multiple cells and try to display that. The same UIView cannot be part of only one subview hierarchy.

What needs to be done instead is to make is a custom background view which has a UIImage configurable with UIAppearance.

Basically one should configure the background view's image using UIAppereance  and not the background view itself.